# VB6 Member variable inheritance

Tags: variables, inheritance, vb6, member

I'm having trouble inheriting a (public) variable, let's say

```
Public Var As ClassThatIsIndependent
```

The declaration above generates no trouble for itself, however, if i inherit the class that holds it

```
Implements BaseClass
```

I get the error "object module needs to implement variable for interface". I've tried these options (both inside ChildClass)

```
Public Var As ClassThatIsIndependent
```

and

```
Public BaseClass_Var As ClassThatIsIndependent
```

But none of them solves the problem. Any alternative? I'm open to possible Set/Get solutions, however, i'd prefer to maintain Var as a public variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the Visual Basic 6.0 Programmer's Guide, Polymorphism, [Implementing Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242062%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) section:

> Suppose we give the Animal class an Age property, by adding a Public variable to the Declarations section:
>
> ```
> Option Explicit
> Public Age As Double
> ```
>
> The Procedure drop downs in the code modules for the Tyrannosaur and Flea classes now contain property procedures for implementing the Age property,
>
> …
>
> Using a public variable to implement a property is strictly a convenience for the programmer. Behind the scenes, Visual Basic implements the property as a pair of property procedures.
>
> You must implement both procedures. The property procedures are easily implemented by storing the value in a private data member, as shown here:
>
> ```
> Private mdblAge As Double
>
> Private Property Get Animal_Age() As Double
>    Animal_Age = mdblAge
> End Property
>
> Private Property Let Animal_Age(ByVal RHS As Double)
>    mdblAge = RHS
> End Property
> ```
>
> The private data member is an implementation detail, so you have to add it yourself.

That is, the "public interface" is exactly the same whether you use a Public variable or define them with Property Get/Let. And to implement a property in an interface, you can't use the Public variable approach and need to use the Property Get/Let syntax and handle the data storage for it in your own private variables.

Comment: After nearly 20 years people still never think to crack open the manual.  Weird.  By now they ought to realize that VB6 has some of the best docs ever produced, imperfect for sure but far better than most others.  This is probably one reason why VB6 always gets such low Tiobe "begging for help" rankings.

Comment: @Bob77 Well, I'm guessing that many people forced to use VB6 nowadays don't still have the original manual that came in the box. I'm honestly amazed that the text is still on Microsoft's site.

Comment: Love or hate Microsoft, they never had a problem with documentation (and still do not).